# How to get distinct record from Table based on priority of column values in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have one table and want to get distinct record for each 'ID' based on 'Status'. Query should check first priority-'Approved', Second Priority - 'Pending' & Third Priority - 'Rejected' and display only record for each ID.

```
    ID      Name        age     Location        Status
101     Sitha       19          IND         Pending
101     Sitha       19          IND         Approved
101     Sitha       19          IND         Rejected
102     Ram         21          US          Pending
102     Ram         21          US          Rejected
103     Sunny       17          UK          Rejected
104     Bunny       22          Canada      Pending
104     Mahesh      28          Brazil      Rejected
105     Suresh      22          Maxico      Rejected
```

I tried with below query but couldn't able to get the expected output.

```
SELECT id,name,age,location,status
FROM
db.sample
WHERE id='1' AND (status="Approved" OR status="Pending" OR status="Rejected")
```

Expected Output should be :

```
101     Sitha   19      IND         Approved
102     Ram     21      US          Pending
103     Sunny   17      UK          Rejected
104     Bunny   22      Canada      Pending
105     Suresh  22      Maxico      Rejected
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses window functions:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by (case status when 'Approved' then 1 when 'Pending' then 2 when 'Rejected' then 3 else 4)
                               ) as seqnum
      from db.sample s
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I tried your query but I'm getting all three records for Id value. I want to get only one record for each id. My question is edited now. Please go through once again and help.

Comment: @Rummy . . . This query *cannot* be returning three rows per id.  The `partition by` is on `id` and `row_number()` only gives one of rows a value of `1`.